# динамический перебор с помощью each jquery

Tags: jquery

На странице, я добавляю новые инпуты. Мне из них нужно получить введённые значения, но как ни пробую всё никак не работает.

```
$(".add_new_list").on("click", "#add_new_list", function(){
    $(this).parent().each(function(){
        one_text = $(this).children(".new_name_menu").val();
        alert(one_text);
    })
    return false;
})
```

alert = undefined

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решён

```
$(".new_name_menu").each(function(index, elem) {
    one_text = $(elem).val();
});
```